# Rewrite SQL in cakephp3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

This is my query in for MySQL:

```
select u.full_name, c.comment_content from users u, comments  WHERE u.user_id=c.user_id
```

How do I have rewrite this SQL using `find()` in cakephp?

Comment: Do you have your Users and Comments tables set up correctly, with associations (e.g. `hasMany`) as required? If so, `$this->Users->find()->contain(['Comments']);` should get you something close (perhaps close enough?) to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

```
$query = $this->Users
    ->find()
    ->select(['full_name', 'comment_content'])
    ->where(['user_id =' => $cUserID])
    ->order(['created' => 'DESC']); //extra
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html